# Finding Which Class[i] queue I Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, classname

I wanna learn which classname[i] number I am clicking.. I wanna learn what is "i" when I click.. How can I get that data?

```js
    function findclassquee(id) {
alert ("I am confused please help me about finding which one I am?; *<<<document.getElementsByClassName('trying')[1] or  *document.getElementsByClassName('trying')[5]>>> ");

    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="findclassquee(this.id)" class="trying">Which Class </button>
<button onclick="findclassquee(this.id)" class="trying">Which Class </button>
<button onclick="findclassquee(this.id)" class="trying">Which Class </button>
<button onclick="findclassquee(this.id)" class="trying">Which Class </button>
<button onclick="findclassquee(this.id)" class="trying">Which Class </button>
<button onclick="findclassquee(this.id)" class="trying">Which Class </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I want , at last I found that :

```js
$(".trying").click(function(){alert($(".trying").index(this));});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Youy can do it like this, with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
var elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.trying'));
// Listen for clicks on each element
elems.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', findclassquee));

function findclassquee() {
  // Find the index of the clicked one
  var index = elems.indexOf(this);
  alert(`You clicked on the element at index ${index}`);
}
```

```html
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
<button class="trying">Which Class</button>
```

Note: I'm using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to an Array, and be able to use Array methods on it, like [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: isnt there a simple code like , getclassqueue(trying) ??

Comment: No, not natively (I'm also unfamiliar with what you call a "queue", there is no "queue" concept in the DOM, but maybe you are referring to something you saw a library do?)

Comment: your solution is what ı want no problem queue means = [i] .. I am ok with your solution .. just wonder maybe there is a shortest version do directly get the indexf

Comment: - i think this the shortest way but what I'm thinking about is that you want a more clear way you can resplace `this.id` into your html onclick attribute with just `this` then you can try the following function

Comment: ```function findclassquee(el) {
  var trying = document.getElementsByClassName("trying");
  for(var i = 0; i < trying.length; i++) {
   if(trying[i] === el) {
    console.log(i)
   }
  }
 }```

Comment: this seems risky way if more than 1 datas are absulatly same

Comment: @blex please can you check that question also ? ;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129502/create-new-button-doesnt-call-class